# How can I dump whole database or individial database using mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to backup mongoDB database using mongodump from replicaset. Script I am using works fine to dump db from remote to local. Same script errors out saying authentication failed when I trying to dump from replicaset.

Is there a simple way I can have whole db dump otherwise specific db dump will be preferred.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="mongorep1:27017,mongorep2:27017,mongorep3:27017"
REMOTE_DB="Products"
LOCAL_DB="Products"
USER="AppUser"
PASS="password"

## DUMP THE REMOTE
echo "Dumping '$HOST:$PORT/$REMOTE_DB'..."
mongodump --host $HOST --db $REMOTE_DB -u $USER -p $PASS --out dump/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`

echo "Done."
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using replicaset with mongodump, you need to prefix the string pass to `--host` with the replicaset name. For instance if your replicaset name is `myreplicaset_name` then it should look like -

`HOST="myreplicaset_name/mongorep1:27017,mongorep2:27017,mongorep3:27017"`

Comment: Hi @Abhay. I tried with prefix but it is dumping admin db not the Products db. I am using products credential.

`#!/bin/bash

HOST="rs0/mongorep1:27017,mongorep2:27017,mongorep3:27017"
REMOTE_DB="Products"
LOCAL_DB="Products"
USER="AppUser"
PASS="password"

## DUMP THE REMOTE
echo "Dumping '$HOST:$PORT/$REMOTE_DB'..."
mongodump --host $HOST:$PORT -u $USER -p $PASS -d $REMOTE_DB --out /usr/local/bin/dump/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`

echo "Done."`

Comment: If you are able to dump admin with the credentials then you can dump all. Just remove the `-d $REMOTE_DB` part and it will dump all the dbs.